# Will several SQLite connections lead to performance issues?

Tags: sqlite

Part of my GUI operates on Foo objects.  The Foo objects can come from multiple sources but I want the GUI to treat them all equally.  In other words, I don't want the GUI to manage database connections, file-handles, etc... so I've come up with the following object model.

```
class Foo {
  // some properties
}

class LocalFoo extends Foo {
   // local id
   // SQLite connection
   // constructor that populates Foo's properties from the database
   // destructor to clean-up
   // override property setters to write to database
}
```

Could the following approach lead to performance issues or obscure bugs (i.e. too many handles) if each object has its own database connection.  Basically, would having 1000 file-handles to the same SQLite database be a problem?

From my understanding, Shared-Cache Mode (https://www.sqlite.org/sharedcache.html) could be used prevent the creation of multiple file-handles by having SQLite use a single file-handle for all the connections.  Would it be alright to have a 1000 database connections when using Shared-Cache Mode?

Comment: Why do you think you can't use a single connection?

Comment: I could, but then there is the question of who closes the connection when all the objects that use it are destroyed.

Comment: Use a reference count.